# UI Issues while Scrolling a Webpage using Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

Im relatively new to Selenium and faced this particular issue while Scrolling inside a DIV. 
I used the following code for Scrolling

```
 < je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", driver.findElement(By.id("rowOfTable_"+reset_on_dropdown_boundry))); >
```

*[reset_on_dropdown_boundry-> is the row number in numerals,eg.rowOfTable_1, implemented a loop to navigate through the rows to get the data]*

Now the problem that i face is while using the above piece of code even though the Scroll is working the alignment of the page changes the other button/dropdowns etc move due to which other automation actions on the same doesnt work.

Is there any other way to scroll through a div without causing any UI issues, tried with mouseActions , but the same didnt help.

Here is the DIV on which i am trying to perform the action,

```
 <div class="slimScrollBar ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="width: 8px; position: absolute; top: 0px; opacity: 1; border-radius: 8px; z-index: 99; right: 0px; height: 255.346px; display: none; background: rgb(124, 145, 151);"></div>
 <div class="slimScrollRail" style="width: 8px; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; border-radius: 8px; opacity: 0.3; z-index: 90; right: 0px; display: none; background: rgb(144, 141, 141);"></div>
```

Comment: Forgot to post your `<div>` ?

Comment: It's there below the line 'Here is the DIV on which i am trying to perform the action,'